# Полифонический/полифоничный - может ли хоть одно из этих слов быть синонимом к многоголосому хору?

Tags: стилистика, синонимы, паронимы

Я ищу синоним к слову "многоголосый":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Итак, перед нами целая художественная симфония, скорее даже
> многоголосый хор, каждый из голосов которого прекрасен сам по себе,
> однако истинное произведение рождается лишь тогда, когда звучат они в
> унисон.

Это некое иносказание - речь об эклектичном грандиозном архитектурном произведении, которое пытаются "довести до ума".

Хочется уйти от "многоголосого хора, каждый из голосов которого".

---

Полифонический{ –} — прилагательное от слова полифония; многозвучный, многоголосный. Большой словарь иностранных слов. Издательство «ИДДК», 2007.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как лучше выйти из положения?

Или и так всё красиво?

Comment: Назовите хор "многозвучным" (много _разных_ голосов"; полифонический" - излишне терминологично) или просто "большим" (= много людей, и все голосят). Эпитет "полифоничный" скорее, указывает на наличие внешних признаков, роднящих описуемое с термином "полифонический" (словарь в соотв. статье вместо Академичности "малость" свою проявляет).

Comment: Саша, но у меня же есть пояснение: *Это некое иносказание - речь об эклектичном грандиозном архитектурном произведении, которое пытаются "довести до ума".* Полифония/полифоничность как архитектурный термин мне кажется уместным и логичным... Но сомнения остаются; ими и порождён вопрос.

Comment: Не заметил, но раз уж автора занесло на "скорее... на хор", надо полезать в кузов :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **МНОГОГОЛОСЫЙ**
>       прил. 1. Состоящий из нескольких, многих звуков, голосов, звучащих одновременно; производимый многими голосами. отт. Издающий много
>   звуков; шумный. 2. Построенный на сочетании нескольких одновременно
>   звучащих мелодических линий голосов (в музыке); полифонический.
>
> Ефремова. Новый словарь русского языка Ефремовой. 2005

Ссылка из сети. Не знаю, есть ли разница для музыковедов, но для широкой аудитории вряд ли "многоголосый" будет здесь резать слух.

Comment: grizzly, Вы, возможно, пропустили в вопросе фразу: *Хочется уйти от "многоголосого хора, каждый из голосов которого"*... И речь об архитектурном ансамбле: *Это некое иносказание - речь об эклектичном грандиозном архитектурном произведении, которое пытаются "довести до ума".*

Comment: То есть, там акцент на "разнобой"? Тогда _разноголосый_.

Comment: @Galina Avanesova Вы правы, был невнимателен.

Comment: Саша, разноголосый не лечит моего страданья - многоголосья, в обоих случаях корень "голос", я же хотела бы избавиться от возможно кажущейся тавтологии. (Не  уверена в своих запятых! Но выделить *возможно* или *возможно кажущейся* почему-то рука не поднимается! Сейчас народ спрошу!)

Comment: @grizzly, давайте Вы уже повнимательнили и исправили/дополнили ответ! )))

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Я бы лучше его удалил, чтоб не вводить других в заблуждение тем, что вопрос отвечен, но пропадут не мои комментарии. Вы не против?

Comment: Против! Я тебе пятёрочку поставила! Размышляй!

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova По правде говоря, я не вижу особых проблем. Сперва используется метафора, затем уже она (эта метафора) обыгрывается, развивается. Мне даже с учётом архитектурного контекста слух не режет.

Comment: Главный вопрос, который (ответ на который) сделает ответ  grizzly понятным: *Хочется уйти от "многоголосого хора, каждый из голосов которого".* НЕ ТАВТОЛОГИЯ ЛИ?

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Я не вижу здесь тавтологии / повторения и т.п. Нормальное построение, такое встречается очень часто.